# What is the main concept of using lexical,linguistic, semantic or syntactic approach in NLP for cyberbullying

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, python

Am really in need of some explanation, am working on a nlp cyberbullying detection tool which i will deploy to the web using django framework, however, am stuck on some idea, can someone explain to me....What is the main concept of using lexical,linguistic, semantic or syntactic approach in (NLP) and how is applied in cyberbullying or what are the step, i know POS-tag is way of grouping word and look for dependency in other word, my idea of pos-tag is a synonym of semantic because pos-tagging is a process linking words to it root and representation word in a understandable context correct me if wrong.

I read an article where a paper tackled a project using predictive analysis approach with feature extraction techniques, navie baye for classification and to train the model, in the discussion they also spoke on how other team used Semantics approach to classifier cyber bullying . I know of data cleaning, tokenisation stemming and most of feature extraction model, however, am stuck on the problem of approach which is what is the relevant on lexical, semantic or syntactic and how are they been approached.

Comment: Trying to summarize an entire approach for cyberbullying detection might be a bit much for a single answer here. I'd suggest trying to find research papers on the subject and reading about them, as well as learning about NLP (maybe read a textbook or take an online course).

Comment: can you suggest me some value.